# Why does the first parameter in getLocation doesn't execute as a function?

Tags: javascript, getlocation

How can I execute the function `accept` in `updatePosition` ? Why can `deny`execute itself but not `accept` ?

```
 accept = alert(123);
 deny = alert(123);

 function getLocation(accept,deny) { 
    
    if (navigator.geolocation) {     
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            updatePosition(position, accept);
        }, deny);
    } else {
      deny;
    }

  }

  function updatePosition(position, accept) {
    PositionLat = position.coords.latitude;
    PositionLon = position.coords.longitude;    
    accept;

  }
```

Comment: Just use `accept()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I execute the function accept in updatePosition ?

Put `()` after the name.

> Why can denyexecute itself

It can't. You are passing `deny` as an argument to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. The code in `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` calls it.